# add a Callback function to a plugin (colorPicker)

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-callback

I have a jQuery plugin I am trying to add a callback function for.
(I will not post all the code, but have provided [a ready made JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ab7cU/) instead: http://jsfiddle.net/39Uqr/)

**[View the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ab7cU/)** - *(after colour is selected, I want to fire a callback)*

The plugin is quite simple, but I am having trouble adding a callback function for after a user has selected a colour. (So once a user has clicked on the box, the colorpicker shows, then once they select a colour, I would like to run a callback function [for ajax update], after the input field has been updated (it does it already)).

So basically, I need a callback function for when after a colour has been selected and updated the input.

I read the following posts on SO, and attempted this myself (for the last 2 hours!!), but just couldn't get it to work.

**[View the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ab7cU/)**

a simple explanation would be very appreciated (optional, *just need it working tho*).

[jQuery Plugin: Adding Callback functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534436/jquery-plugin-adding-callback-functionality)
*and also tried*
[jQuery plugin callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545406/jquery-plugin-callback)

The plugin is called '[Reallysimplecolorpicker](http://laktek.com/2008/10/27/really-simple-color-picker-in-jquery/)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made up a demo for you that I think is what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/ab7cU/4/

I added a comment `// New line!` for every new line that I added to the code.

`this` inside the callback refers to the element that you apply colorPicker to. Later that element will be removed from the DOM.

I added an example that alert the rel attribute ;-)

Comment: Good solution, but shouldn't the `callback` variable be inside the `$.each`? This way there will be a shared callback to every instance of the plugin.

Comment: Yeah, of course. But I thought it was obvious. I will update my answer ;-)

Comment: @JustAnil No, its 3 lines. This one also: callback(value); // New line!

Comment: I just want to mention that you cannot refer to *this* inside the callback function. Is it good enough?

Comment: I can have a look on it later, its possible. What do you want *this* should represent, couse when I looked to it colorPicker replace the input with its own markup. So *this* don't exist, but you can point *this* to a copy of the HTML element that apply the picker. What are you trying to do? Maybe I can help you if you explain